# What is Quirks Mode in IE? When and Why we use Quirks Mode in internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

I saw Quirks Mode in development tools, but i didn't understand the purpose of it. I have did lot of google for it; but no success.

It shows broken HTML. Is it a HTML validator or what please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Quirks Mode" means the browser tries to work in compatibility mode with older browser versions. Quirks mode kicks in if browser detects the site was coded/optimized for earlier versions of the browser.

You wrote you googled it and possibly hit this article, but in case you didn't:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

"(...)a technique used by some web browsers for the sake of maintaining backward compatibility with web pages designed for older browsers(...)"

If you want a test, try this little guy (works both in Firefox and Internet Explorer -9-) here:

```
<HTML>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=6" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<script>
window.alert('You are in ' + (document.compatMode==='CSS1Compat'?'Standards':'Quirks') + ' mode.')
</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Copy-paste the code above in a blank text file, save & rename it to [anything].html, then drag&drop to your browser. It'll display a message box telling you the browser is in quirks mode.
If you remove the meta tag, save the file & refresh browser page you'll see the browser switched back to standard mode.

There can be many reasons something says an HTML is broken but in your case, one good reason could be you force compatibility to old browser version(s) but use technology in your code that was invented later.
E.g. using "canvas" element (HTML5) and forcing IE6 compatibility (which is an old browser and doesn't understand HTML5 elements).

Comment: Is there any relationship between Quirks Mode and DOCTYPE?

Comment: yes there is! ppl say "DOCTYPE" forces permanent quirks mode but in fact -at least in IE9- it forces standard mode instead. if you add "<!DOCTYPE HTML>" to the sample html I added above, browser(s) will report standard mode instead of quirks mode, even if IE6 compatibility is somewhat 'forced' by the meta tag